# What is the backstory behind the White Sun of Angola?

Tags: africa, national-symbols, angola

I was reading some history of Angola and came across this symbol, for which the filename was "White Sun of Angola".

I was unable to find anything that explains its origin with some simple google searches, does anyone know the history of this symbol?[image]

Comment: See http://create-recreate.blogspot.com/2014/08/angola.html

Comment: And https://web.archive.org/web/20040622113124/http://www.angola.org/referenc/proposed_flag.html

Comment: "The image is inspired by rock paintings in the desert cave of Tchitundo-Hulu in Namibe Province. The sun symbolizes the historical and cultural identity and the riches of Angola." - quote from [this page](https://www.crwflags.com/fotw/flags/ao!.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [FOTW Flags Of The World](https://www.crwflags.com/fotw/flags/ao!.html), the sun symbol appeared in the flag proposed by the National Assembly's Constitutional Commission in 2003. The proposal saw some opposition and never became law. The symbol is:

> ... a 15-ray yellow sun comprised of three irregular concentric circles. The image is inspired by rock paintings in the desert cave of Tchitundo-Hulu in Namibe Province. The sun symbolizes the historical and cultural identity and the riches of Angola.
>
> The design was submitted by a candidate under the nickname of "Catica", whose proposal was numbered 106. According to the contest regulations, the winner is entitled to a medal and an amount in the local currency equivalent to USD20 000.

[image]

Compare it to the suns and circles from the Tchitundo-Hulu rock art:

[image: A sun]
[image: A sun made of concentric circles]
[image: Concentric circles]

Comment: Was in the process of adding an essentially identical answer. Bravo! Allow me to offer up a useful link I found about [the cave art](http://www.rinasherman.com/film/TchitunduHulu/RockArt.html), and another about [the failed flag effort](https://web.archive.org/web/20040622113124/http://www.angola.org/referenc/proposed_flag.html). Also added a pic of the flag in question. Shame about that, its much more unique than their current one.

Answer (score 0):

The symbol appears to be a visual reference to [this book on the Angolan civil war](https://www.wilsoncenter.org/sites/default/files/adamishin_-_white_sun_of_angola_0.pdf) by Anatoly Adamishin.

From the final chapter (**my emphasis**):

> It was only in 2002, and only with Savimbi’s death - he was killed in a shoot-out with governmental troops – that civil war in Angola came to the end. It lasted more than a quarter of a century, had taken from a half million to one and a half million lives and ravaged a potentially very rich country. **The sun over Angola was white, not only from the heat but from human suffering, too.**

Comment: The name of the book seems to be a reference to the soviet movie "White Sun of the Desert".